# Was Akira manipulating Tetsuo?

Tags: akira

The [casting call](http://www.acting-auditions.org/2011/11/casting-now-underway-for-leo-dicaprio.html?m=1) for the upcoming remake of Akira includes a story summary that includes the following description:

> Ky believes Tetsuo is headed to release a young boy, Akira, who has taken control of Tetsuo's mind.

I don't recall anything in the original movie that suggested that Akira was influencing Tetsuo's actions or thoughts.  Was there anything in the original movie to suggest that Akira was influencing Tetsuo's actions?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a really long time since I've seen the film, and I'm not familiar with the manga at all.  I do recall wondering exactly what drew Tetsuo to Akira and the stadium, but it didn't feel like he was being controlled by Akira.  But it's not too much of a stretch to portray it that way.

Looking at the casting call link, other details seem to have changed too, such as Tetsuo being Kaneda's brother, rather than a long-time childhood friend.  Again, minor.  Only time will tell just how much Hollywood will change it, however.

Comment: I've read the Manga, and while the titular Akira has a much more expanded role there, I do not recall him consciously manipulating Tetsuo. He's portrayed more as a somewhat neutral force of nature.